# Live-migration of a SLES9 DomU?

Tags: xen

With SLES9 SP4 we managed to set up a XEN PV DomU.

We are using SLES10 SP4 as Dom0 and DRBD 8 as disc-backed: a drbd-device corresponds to xvda in the DomU. The DomU uses the xenblk and xennet drivers, so everything seems ok.

We applied the last patches (EoL of SLES9 SP4 was on 31th of August). After live-migration to another Dom0 the DomU seems to crash. No reaction to SYSRQ, nothing on the console. DRBD switches from one side (primary) to the other, so the disk-backend does not seem to be a problem here. With CentOS 4/5, SLES 10/11 DomUs we never had an issue with live-migration.
Even W2K3 works.

After destroy/create of the DomU it comes up without problems, last-log shows a "crash" entry.

Any hints are welcome...

Comment: Does this happen every time you migrate the domU? Does it happen with other domUs? Have you contacted Novell support?

Comment: Yes - every time. No - I have not contacted SLES-support since sles9 has EoLed - I am not even sure that Novell did officially support sles9 in DomU PV mode.

Comment: @MikeyB I just tried my luck with a SLES-SR. It got closed because of EoL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options. Good luck :(

- **Contact Novell support**
  It never hurts to try. And the problem may lie on the dom0.
- **Convert sles9 domU to be full virt instead of paravirt**
  It's possible that something in the paravirt side of things in sles9 is getting screwed up. Perhaps running the same image as full virtualization would avoid that.
- **Upgrade to something supported**
  Has to be said, though I suspect you would have done so already if you could.

Comment: I have enough first hand experience with novell support so that I can foresay that they will close the case because SLES9 is EoL. Full-virt: This would propably work - the latest patch for sles9sp4 was a patch for pv-drivers in hvm mode that will prevent a crash during live-migrate. :-( BUT: I use XEN because it does PV. So currently I don`t live-migrate my SLES9. Upgrade: I am pinned to SLES9 due to an old program that will be in use for a while. Afterwards that program will work with sles11.